# How do I make a 0 value NULL in my results using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that selects a list of customers, and how many times we have performed a service, which I can reset whenever I want. When we have not been there, the value shows up as zero, when I would rather it just not show up at all. How can I do this?

here is the code:

```
$query = "  SELECT * 
            FROM customers b
            JOIN customerRoutes a
            ON a.customerPK=b.customerPK
            WHERE a.inches <= $inches
            AND a.routesPK = $route_name
            AND $day
            AND b.active=1
            ;";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Customers</th><th>Times Visited</th>
                                </tr>";

while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> <a href='snow.php?technician=".$technician."&customer=".$row['customerName']."&route=".$row['routesPK']."&service=".$newService."&customerPK=".$row['customerPK']."' target='iframe_a' >".$row['customerName']."</a></td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['occurences']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

The trouble is near the bottom, its "OCCURENCES". I've tried using NULLIF but I'm not sure where it should go properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The MySQL `NULLIF()` function can be wrapped around a column reference in the SELECT list.  Replace the lazy, performance hogging `*` with a proper list of qualified column references and expressions.  **`SELECT b.customerName, b.customerPK, NULLIF(b.occurrences,0) AS occurrences FROM`**.

Comment: Excellent, that did it for me. I was simply using the select * for testing purposes. I had tried this before but without an alias.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it using PHP, e.g.

```php
echo "<td>" . ($row['occurences'] > 0 ? $row['occurences'] : "") . "</td>";
```

or you can use SQL as @spencer7593 suggested

```sql
SELECT b.customerName, b.customerPK, NULLIF(b.occurrences,0) AS occurrences, ...
```

As an alternative, you can try the standard [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement

```
select b.customerName, b.customerPK,
       case b.occurrences when 0 then null else b.occurrences end
from customers b
```

---

Unrelated, but you should not use `select *`, rather be explicit and name each column, e.g. `select customerName, occurences, ...`.

Comment: I need to be able to show all customers on the specific route still. Both of these will only give me a list of customers who have already been visited. Currently my list looks like this:

Jim    1
Bob   0
Bill     0
Mary  0
Jill      2

but I want it to look like this:

Jim    1
Bob   
Bill     
Mary  
Jill      2

Comment: Also, I can't get the formatting to work right on my comment, so hopefully you can understand it.

Comment: Then I have misunderstood your question, please see updated answer.